# How to keep the format of other number by extracting the integer part of number using xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there any possibility when applying the following xsl code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="fils1"><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".='C_RE'">
            <fils><xsl:value-of select="." /></fils>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fils><xsl:value-of select="floor(.)*(. >= 0) + ceiling(.) * not(. >= 0)"/>      </fils><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

on this xml file:

```
<Racine>
<el1>
    <fils1 >2.13</fils1>
    <fils1>012</fils1>
    <fils1>-31.45</fils1>
    <fils1>C_RE</fils1>
</el1>

</Racine>
```

to get this output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fils>2</fils>

<fils>012</fils>

<fils>-31</fils>

<fils>C_RE</fils>
```

For the moment I can get on the second line of my result this: `<fils>12</fils>` and I want to get the digit **0** in my result like this: `<fils>012</fils>`.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="fils1[number() = number()]">
        <fils>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat(.,'.'), '.')"/>
        </fils>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fils1">
      <fils><xsl:copy-of select="node()"/></fils>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Racine>
    <el1>
        <fils1>2.13</fils1>
        <fils1>012</fils1>
        <fils1>-31.45</fils1>
        <fils1>C_RE</fils1>
    </el1>
</Racine>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<fils>2</fils>
<fils>012</fils>
<fils>-31</fils>
<fils>C_RE</fils>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using the fact that an expression to test if the string value of the current node is a correct representation of a number is: `number() = number()` .
2. Proper use of sentinel programming.

Comment: I wanted to change the tag name `<fils1>` into `<fils>` after the transformation.In the xsl code, I changed the **fils1** with **fils** and I could get the correct result, but the line `<fils1>C_RE</fils1>` stayed unchanged and I also want to have it changed into `<fils>C_RE</fils>`

Comment: @FrankyN., I updated my answer. Now the code produces exactly your desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It walks very well now.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of leading zeros ( = string-length(x) - string-length(number(x)), perhaps) and add them back at the end, though of course this kind of string manipulation in XSLT 1.0 is very fiddly.

Comment: I thank also to count the length of a number, but I'm not an expert in xslt and I don't know to do it. Could you help please to modify my xsl code so that it walks well? Thanks